# filter Catalog Search Results based on Attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I get search results based on the search like http://crowdedgallery.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/index/?&q=cats

And I want to refine it more by adding another attribute to the search by
http://crowdedgallery.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/index/?orientation=landscape&p=3&q=cats

Where I have the values of the attribute "Orientation" as "Landscape" and "Portrait",

I know it is possible to filter using the Search in Layered Navigation, but I just want to FILTER the Search Results  after the output with "Orientation"

Is it possible to change something in the Query.php or any other methods,

please help,

I am new to magento and am stuck,

Answer (score 2):

You need to select yes for the highlighted options use in quick search and use in search results layered navigation & use in layered navigation as filterable(with results). [image]

Comment: Hi, No, I want to filter the Search Results More using attributes,  something like q=Cats&orientation=Landscape

Comment: For this you can use magento catalog advanced search. You can go this url for advanced search your_site_url/catalogsearch/advanced

Comment: can i use the q=cats with the attributes in the advanced searc?

Comment: To be more specific please see this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59745/modify-catalogsearch-module-to-search-by-attribute-values

Comment: how or where to add this in magento

Comment: @user31637 the short answer is yes you can use the query string in the advanced search

Comment: Could you perhaps say where in admin you can find these options??